# Best approach to render read only content in Vue

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code that I'm using to render messages between 2 users

```
 <template>
    <main>
        <form action="" method="post" @submit.prevent="sendMessage">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"> </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>    
        <section v-if="messages.length">
            <div v-for="message in messages">
                    {{message.body}}
                    <hr>
            </div>    
        </section>
        <section v-else>
                No messages
        </section>
    </main>
</template>
<script>
    import ajax from './ajax';
    export default {
        data () {
            return {                  
                messages: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendMessage(e){                    
            },
            getMessages(pageNum, cb){
                ajax({
                         url: `${window.location.pathname}?p=${pageNum}`,
                         method: 'get',
                         callback(res){
                             cb(JSON.parse(res)); 
                         }
                     })
            }

        },
        created(){
            var vm = this;
            vm.getMessages(1, (res) => {
                vm.messages = res.data;
                vm.loaded=true;

            });

        }
    }
</script>
```

Specifically the code `v-for="message in messages"`, the `message` property in my component.
These messages will be read only so there will be no event listeners or anything. So it will not be the best way to keep them in array after the ajax call. However, there will be a load more button that loads 10 messages in a call and those will be appended to array.

So I want to ask how do I go about this without keeping the messages in array after rendering but still keeping them on the page? 
Or if you can suggest a better, efficient, way to implement this, I will appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you store the messages in the `messages` array?

Comment: @thanksd I can store but as I mentioned, I want to know if there's a better way to do without it since keeping them in array isn't necessary.

Comment: It is necessary because the component could/will be re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind Vue is that your model drives what is in the view. If it goes away in your model, it goes away in your view. If you want it to be present in your view, it should be present in your model.

Comment: Thanks. can you tell how will it affect the memory and performance if there are thousands of messages being rendered using the array ? 
Or how can I assess if it will be good or bad for the client ?

Comment: Thousands of messages in the view will be more of a problem than thousands of messages in memory. I can't tell you how to assess the client's experience, but it seems to me that a client doesn't generally want to look at thousands of messages at a time.